# How to decrypt and analyse data from desktop application

Tags: file-format, encryption, networking

I have a project where I need to analyse some data from a desktop application (WeChat) on Windows. More specifically, I am looking to extract URLs when I search for articles using a particular keyword.

The methods I have tried are searching through the local program files and sniffing the network packets. Here is a little recap of each method, what I tried and what didn't work.

Local Program files method:

I first started by using a rudimentary python script which searched all local files related to WeChat for urls that matched WeChat article structure (https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/....). This returned some results such as my clicked link history. But most results were irrelevant, or completely unreadable. I realised doing it this way is literally searching for a needle in a haystack.

I then decided to use Process Monitor to see which files were opened, read or written to when I used the specific feature I want. This returned better results. When I opened up these files though, I could see some sort of url structure but they were always unreadable. Most of these files which are interesting, I can't figure out how to properly open and read.

Network traffic analysis method:

And so I thought, that the feature uses a cloud service to get the information. Why would the application store it client-side, unless it contains client-specific information (such as the clicked link history), especially when the application needs a network connection to run its basic functionality. So I downloaded WireShark to try and analyse and extract the data from the packets. Again, unreadable and can't figure out how to properly open them.

My guess is that all these files and packets and data are all encrypted. Also, I'd like to add that I don't have any experience in network and low-level type programming. So if I'm missing some trivial things let me know.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions to this problem it would be greatly appreciated.